# HTML 5 validates required input field with display none property and not submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Form. All the fields in that form are required. But some fields are display:none by default and it will only display according to the selection of some dropdown boxes

```
<form class="form" name="my_form" id="my_form">
    <div id="dd">
        <label> Type*</label></div>
    <div class="input"><select onchange="show(this.value);" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-large" id="firmType"
                               name="firmType" required>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Company">Company</option>
        <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
    </select>

    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row" id="show" style="display:none;">
        <div id="label">
            <label> Name*</label></div>
        <div class="input"><input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-large" id="proprietorName" name="proprietorName"
                                  type="text" value="" placeholder="" required></div>
        <div id="label" class="right">
            <label> Company Reg. No*</label></div>
        <div class="input">
            <input class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-large" id="agentRegNumber" name="agentRegNumber" type="text" value=""
                   placeholder="" required>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row">
        <input type="submit" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large AddAgent-button"
               name="AddAgent" id="AddAgent" value="Sign Up"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

function is given below.

```
function show(val) {
    if (val == 'Company') {
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

If I have selected Type as Individual, name and reg no field will not display. but while submitting form it is not submitting since that fields are required.

Comment: So you want a required field to not be required?

Comment: You have error in javascript, `show()` function must be closed `}`

Comment: And a missing `>` for `<div id="dd"`. Proper indentation makes it easier to spot those kind of mistakes. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `required` attribute when fields are not displayed:

```
function show(val) {
    if (val == 'Company') {
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
        setRequired(true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
        setRequired(false);
    }
}

function setRequired(val){
    input = document.getElementById("show").getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        input[i].required = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes..Now form is submitting